Unable to copy Disk Snapshot to Azure Blob storage 'CannotVerifyCopySource' Error
I am trying to copy my snapshot into a BLOB container on Azure but I am getting this error
CannotVerifyCopySource

Message

Server failed to authenticate the request. Please refer to the information in the www-authenticate header.

I tried it based on the article I found here
I have the same code but I am still getting this error. My networking for storage has my IP whitelisted in the firewall as well.
Here is my PowerShell script:
$resourceGroupName = 'RG_DISKS'
$snapshotName = 'DATADISK1'
$resourceGroupNameStorageAccount = 'RG_DISKS'
$storageAccountName = 'STR_001'
$storageContainerName = 'STR_001_DISK1'
$destinationVHDFileName = 'DATADISK1_vhd'

$storageAccountKey = Get-AzStorageAccountKey -resourceGroupName $resourceGroupNameStorageAccount -AccountName $storageAccountName
$sas = Grant-AzSnapshotAccess -ResourceGroupName $resourceGroupName -SnapshotName $snapshotName  -DurationInSecond 3600 -Access Read

$destinationContext = New-AzStorageContext -StorageAccountName $storageAccountName -StorageAccountKey ($storageAccountKey).Value[0]


Start-AzStorageBlobCopy -AbsoluteUri $sas.AccessSAS -DestContainer $storageContainerName -DestContext $destinationContext -DestBlob $destinationVHDFileName

Is there something am I missing here?

Server failed to authenticate the request. Please refer to the information in the www-authenticate header.

The above error message "Server failed to authenticate the request. The www-authenticate header usually indicates that the request to the Azure Storage service was not properly authenticated.
To resolve the issue, make sure to set the SAS validity to a longer value, such as 86400 seconds. This will generate a SAS that is valid for 24 hours.
Check that the storage account and container exist and that you have the correct permissions to write to the container.
Check that the storage account network firewall is configured to allow traffic from your public IP address or enabled from all networks.
Here is PowerShell script to download the snapshot to Azure blob.
    $resourceGroupName = 'RG-Name'
    $snapshotName = 'venkat-snapshot'
    $resourceGroupNameStorageAccount = 'RG-Name'
    $storageAccountName = 'venkatstoarage'
    $storageContainerName = 'snapshot'
    $destinationVHDFileName = 'DATADISK1_vhd'
    
    $storageAccountKey = Get-AzStorageAccountKey -resourceGroupName $resourceGroupNameStorageAccount -AccountName $storageAccountName
    $sas = Grant-AzSnapshotAccess -ResourceGroupName $resourceGroupName -SnapshotName $snapshotName  -DurationInSecond 86400 -Access Read
    $destinationContext = New-AzStorageContext -StorageAccountName $storageAccountName -StorageAccountKey ($storageAccountKey).Value[0]
    Start-AzStorageBlobCopy -AbsoluteUri $sas.AccessSAS -DestContainer $storageContainerName -DestContext $destinationContext -DestBlob $destinationVHDFileName

storageAccountKey permission

After running the code, the snapshot has started copying to the Blob container.

Reference: Azure Blob Storage fails to authenticate: "Make sure the value of Authorization header is formed correctly including the signature
AzureStorage Blob Server failed to authenticate the request.

Thanks Venkat for the answer, I tried extending the time but I am still getting the same error. I have full permission to the keys as well. The permissions on the storage container, I am the owner of the storage container. Can you let me know what permissions should I have or can you show what permissions are required

It's not required to have any RBAC role, as you are using a SAS token. Please check the permissions assigned to the SAS token and also enabled all networks in the storage account and check the status.

Yeah I think that's the issue, my policy wouldn't allow Anonymous access to these resources and I need to use my Azure AD account to access these resources. How can I do that with my AAD account?

Hi @progrAmmar,
Change the container authentication method to Microsoft Enterprise user account and assign the role  Storage Blob Data Contributor , and ensure that the Get-AzStorageAccountKey cmdlet is removed from your script, refer the Ms Link for more details.

Thanks for the suggestion, I tried that, Container Authentication "Microsoft Entra user account" and I have the "Storage Blob Data Owner" Permission on the Storage account. Still getting the same error
Start-AzStorageBlobCopy: Server failed to authenticate the request. Please refer to the information in the www-authenticate header.
Status 401 (Server failed to authenticate the request. Please refer to the information in the www-authenticate header. )
ErrorCode: CannotVerifyCopySource

Try enabling all networks in storage account and check once.

Let us continue this discussion in chat.
